# Whole and fraction to float/double?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

If I have a signed long variable that holds the whole number part of a decimal and another long variable that holds the fraction part, how would I convert that to a float or double type?

The fraction part is scaled to the 9th place.

Example:
signed long h = -5;
long f = 200073490

Result should be -5.20007349

Example 2:
signed long h = 3;
long f = 500100;

Result should be 3.0005001

Edit
Also: looking for a mathematical solution. Converting to string and scanning it back into float/double will not work in my project.

Comment: is this for c or c++?

Comment: Visual studio C++

Comment: `char buffer[64]; double v; sprintf(buffer, "%ld.%ld", h, f); sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &v);` or use `stringstream`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm looking for a mathematical solution. Converting to string and scanning it into a float/double is not viable in my project. Also it's probably extremely slow.

Comment: That info add to post.

Comment: What is the scale of the long? Because if a long of `12345678` should result in `5.12345678`, you would have to divide by `100000000` to get that fraction. But your `73490` would only have to be divided by `100000`. How do you represent a fraction of, say, `0.000123`? Or otherwise, why doesn't your combination result in, say, `5.0007349` or even `5.0000000007349`?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis good question! I hadn't considered it, but the scaling depends on the current operation in my program. For this, if f = 7349 then it would actually be considered -5.0000007349 where the entire long is used. If a scale is needed for this calculation, then it would be to the 7th digit, where 7000000 = .7

Comment: A scale factor is either needed or not. Your example where 7000000 = .7 and 73490 = .73490 has different scale factors. Ten to the 7th in one case and ten to the 5th in the other. If you want both to work you need to take the integer part of log10(f), add one, and use that for the scale factor. You will also need some error checking for 0 or below and flipping the sign to match that of h.  At a minimum.

Comment: I think my last comment was a little misleading. The actual scaling is ten to the 9th place. 73490 is an invalid example because I did not consider scaling. I have edited my original post.

Comment: FWIW, the size of a long is different on different platforms. Often it is a 32 bit value, which would give you up to 10^9, but sometimes it is a 64 bit value, giving you 10^19. I assume on your system it is 10^9?

Comment: Yes, long has 32 bits on my system.

Comment: `double result=h +  (1-2*(h < 0)) * f/1000000000.0;`

Comment: @doug make this an answer and i will mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `long int`, `h`, representing the fractional part is scaled by 1000,000,000 you just need to divide it by 1000000000 and correct for the sign in the event the integer portion of the pair is negative. That is you add the scaled fractional part when the base number is positive and subtract the scaled fractional part when the base number is negative. Given that `h` is the integer portion and `f` is the fractional portion an expression that combines these to produce a double is:

`double result=h + (1-2*(h < 0)) * f/1000000000.0;`

The expression `(1-2*(h < 0))` yields a 1 when h is not negative otherwise a -1.